# How to validate mobile OTP in react js

Tags: reactjs

i am working on small mobile verification project where i am trying to validate a mobile otp from random function, i create two component first is MobileNo. and second is MobileOtp, but now i want validate a mobile otp generated from randome function "rand". but i dont know how do it and i m confused how to make it. please help..

here is my code:-

//MobileNo Component:- from this component i sending an otp to the mobile number

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import API from '../../../api/API';

class MobileNo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {  
      mobile:"",
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  
  
  handleChange(event) { 
    this.setState({[event.target.name]:event.target.value});
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
    
    return;
      
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {          
    event.preventDefault();
    const mobile = this.state.mobile  
    const rand = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
    console.log(rand);
    API.post("/otp?otp="+rand+"&mobile_number="+mobile)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
}
<Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>                      {/*mobile varification form input*/}
                                <Form.Row>
                                    <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                      <Form.Label id="formLabel">Mobile Number</Form.Label>
                                        <Form.Control 
                                        id="formCtrl"
                                          type="text"
                                            name="mobile"
                                            placeholder="Enter Mobile No."
                                            maxLength="10"
                                            value={this.state.mobile}
                                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                                            onBlur={this.handleBlur}
                                            autoComplete="on"  
                                            onKeyPress={(event) => {
                                              if (!/[0-9]/.test(event.key)) {
                                                event.preventDefault();
                                              }
                                            }}                          
                                          />   
                                          {this.state.mobileError && (
                                              <div style={{color:"red"}}>{this.state.mobileError}</div>
                                            )}
                                    </Form.Group>      
                                </Form.Row>
                                <Button type="submit" id="sButton">Submit</Button>
                    </Form>
export default MobileNo;
```

//MobileOtp Compnent:- from this component i am trying validate a Otp but i dont know how to do it please help.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MobileOtp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          otp:"",
isFormSubmitted: false
        };    
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      
      }      
               
      handleChange(event) {                            
        this.setState({[event.target.name]:event.target.value});
        const { name, value } = event.target;    
        this.setState({
          [name]: value
         });      
       return;
      }
    
      handleBlur(event) {
        const { name } = event.target;
    
        this.validateField(name);
        return;
      }
       
      handleSubmit(event) {                                        
        event.preventDefault();                      
       
        let formFields = ["otp",];
        let isValid = true;
        formFields.forEach(field => {
          isValid = this.validateField(field) && isValid;
        });
      
        if (isValid) this.setState({ isFormSubmitted: true });      
        else this.setState({ isFormSubmitted: false });
        return this.state.isFormSubmitted;
      
      }
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <Form.Row>
                                <Form.Group as={Col}>
                                    
                                    <Form.Control id="formMobileCtrl" onClick={this.onLaunchClicked} 
                                        type="text" 
                                        name="otp"
                                        placeholder="Enter OTP."
                                        maxLength="4"
                                        value={this.state.Otp}
                                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                                        onBlur={this.handleBlur}
                                        autoComplete="off"  
                                        onKeyPress={(event) => {
                                          if (!/[0-9]/.test(event.key)) {
                                            event.preventDefault();
                                          }
                                        }}                                     
                                       />                                         
                                </Form.Group>                                    
                                </Form.Row>                        
                                <Button type="submit" id="sButton">Submit</Button>
                            </Form>  
export default MobileOtp
```

Comment: The random number should be generated from the backend, not the front end. You are suppose to send a mobile number to your backend, and backend is suppose to respond with the OTP needed, as well as a identification token. You will then get the user input, and return to your backend with the identification token. Finally, your backend should verify the OTP matches, and the identification token matched, before responding with a "ok"

Comment: ok thank you so much, but is there any alternative to test it from frontend

Comment: What you can do is just to test the random number with the input with === operator though, that's not how it works. Testing should be done on backend.

Comment: ok thank you so much.... i got the point